# "How to fix" admob banner code that 'always return 3' on all new android device?

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

According to my problem,
Admob Banner ads shown on old device not on new devices.
"Test Banner Ads" Shown in all device whereas it is new or old.
Only "Production Banner Ads" not shown on new device. It always show error code 3.

My app already live and around 1M Daily request, but only receive 3k impression. so math rate around 0.8% .

How can i fix this error for banner ads.

Extra note :
My account was 3 year older, and facing this issue since last 2-3 month. My app have not any kind of violation.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL) It happens when no inventory available or no Ad available for your App. I faced same error code with my App when it was banned by Admob, when I even tried to link it with another account it always gave me same error code 3.

So the reason could be due to no inventory or App banned. There could be another reason that App is newly connected to Admob which takes time (sometimes few days) to show ads properly. But as you mentioned you already got 1M users, so that may not be the case.

Comment: I have already read Documentation about that. And my app is not in any kind of violation. But still facing this issue since last 2-3 month. My account is 3 year older.

Comment: I also faced such issue with one by my Apps, which was published on Google play for a specific country France, And in other countries it is mostly not showing ad (return error 3). but in France its working fine. But its just my experience, I couldn't see anything about it in documentation. Thats why I didn't mention in answer, I may be wrong.

Comment: @UmeshDevani these are the possible reasons. And we only can tell the possibilities, Only Admob knows the exact reason, what happened to your App :)

Comment: I have already did many experience on this in different way with various live device, but still facing this issue. Issue cause in latest version phone only with oreo and pie.